# Get string only if it doesn't starts with some char?

Tags: javascript, regex

My String is :

```
'{ color : rgb(0,0,0);background-color : rgb(255, 255, 255);}'
```

I want to match color and background both.

My regexp is

```
a = new RegExp(prop + '[^;]+?\\;','g');
```

where

```
prop = `color` or `background-color`
```

Background matches fine but color matches both. I tried

```
a =new RegExp('[^d-]'+prop + '[^;]+?\\;','g');
```

it matches `;background-color : rgb(255, 255, 255);` but I just want `background-color : rgb(255, 255, 255);`.

1) How do I get that?
2) If I want to remove `background-color` from string, what will be regexp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex and use captured group #1 in replacement:

```
var prop = 'color';
var re =  new RegExp('([^-])' + prop + '\\s*:[^;]+\;');

var s = '{color : rgb(0,0,0);background-color : rgb(255, 255, 255);}'
var r = s.replace(re, '$1 '); // replaces color property by a space
//=> { background-color : rgb(255, 255, 255);}
```

Comment: I got it, but how do I replace background-color or color?

Comment: Isn't it simple enough? Which part seems complicated here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60650/discussion-between-gautam-kumar-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 1):

You could match all the properties first, with this regex:

```
/([\w-]+)\s*:\s*(.+?)[;}]/g
```

With this input:

```
var css = '{\
    color: rgb(0,0,0);\
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\
    font-size: 2em;\
    margin: 0;\
    padding: 4px;\
    font-style: italic;\
    text-align: center;\
  }'
```

It gives this output:

```
var output = {}

s.replace(/([\w-]+)\s*:\s*(.+?)[;}]/g, function(_, k, v) {
  output[k] = isNaN(v) ? v : +v // cast number if necessary
})

console.log(output)
/*^ { color: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
      'background-color': 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
      'font-size': '2em',
      margin: 0,
      padding: '4px',
      'font-style': 'italic',
      'text-align': 'center' }
*/
```

Then you can access the keys you want dynamically:

```
var prop = 'color'
output[prop] //=> rgb(0,0,0)
```

Comment: What if i want to remove some propert?

Comment: Then you do `delete output[prop]`

Comment: Well, if you want to convert from and to CSS then you need to code the other way around too, from the JS object to the CSS string.

Comment: And that's better approach than simply replacing within a string, that way you work with data and transformations, not simply strings.

Comment: If i want to replace just one property from a <style> defined in header, will it be good?